# Block Size Appearance

Tags: html, css

My main website is: http://www.beachildagain.com/
My beta website is: http://becabeta.blogspot.nl/

Both sites were created using Blogger
Running latest Chrome version on a Macbook

Screen width is set (on Blogger) to 960 px with a 276 px sidebar on both sites.

To set up a beta site for testing I copied the code from the main site.  I assumed the results (block sizes) would be identical.  They are not.

All text and block sizes seem to be shrunk about 20% on the new beta site.  The only thing that hasn't changed is the background image.  It is the same size on both.  Coincidentally, the main site also appears shrunk on other browsers.  Both sites may appear the same size (shrunken) on your browser.

Perhaps my main site on my Macbook is the anomaly.

It has been suggested that perhaps the viewport tag is the culprit.  As I understand it, viewport relates to how a page appears on different devices with different screen sizes.  In my case, I'm on the same computer with the same browser.

What could be causing the difference?

Thank you.

Comment: Im gonna have to ask it, sure the zoom isnt wrong? Press ctrl+0 on both websites to set zoom to standard. To me, both the sidebars are the same (on FF 25)

Comment: Oh, and viewports are for mobile devices, not desktop browsers :)

Comment: Zoom is the same on both.  Thanks

Comment: I've checked the sites at work, FF25 works fine, IE8 works fine and Chrome works fine :) Unless im looking at the wrong thing, your problem is local

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure, but did you try setting the viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">.
```

Comment: Here is my code regarding viewport:  <b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
      <meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'/>
    <b:else/>
      <meta content='width=1000' name='viewport'/>  Perhaps you are on the right track.

Comment: I played with variations to viewport setting but no change so far.

Comment: Read specification documents for viewport meta. Im not sure about it. But i guess it is the reason.

Comment: Viewports aren't for desktops, only portable devices (like phones, not laptops)

Comment: Thats y i said i am not sure. Thanx Martinjn. :)